How do I check the status of an LSB service?
If I run
service --status-all

I see a list of all services, including the service (let's call it X), that I'm interested in
Status of X: X is running with the PID Y

If I then do
service status X

I get
The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop, restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other actions, please try to use systemctl.

But if I run
systemctl status X

I see something different, and not what I expect
● X.service - LSB: X
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/X; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2024-06-07 10:44:58 BST; 1 weeks 4 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B

Is there any way to get the status of service X directly, without grepping it out of the output of service --status-all?
Note that /etc/init.d/X does exist and it's a bash script, which has status as a command line option.
Also, note that while this question ultimately has the same answer as Can confirm service is running but can not check it's status I didn't find that question when I did a search, as the error message given in that situation was different to the one I was given here.

"I didn't find that question when I did a search, as the error message given in that situation was different to the one I was given here." ... And that is one of the reasons why we have duplicates, so that people having the same problem worded differently can still be pointed to the right solution
